# Ubuntu 22.04 How do I enable the display of my favorite applications in the gnome menu?

Tags: gnome, 22.04

At Ubuntu 22.04 if you add apps to favorites, it will appear in the dock, but it will no longer be displayed in the menu. How to disable it? I used to deal with Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 20.04, so this innovation is very inconvenient for me.

Comment: English is the [official](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange/13684#13684) language on stachexchange. Please do not post in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Gnome Extension to restore old AppGrid behavior.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4485/favourites-in-appgrid/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly. It is how the Application overview is designed to work in Gnome 40 and up.

The application overview gives an overview of the installed applications. The idea is that an application available for launching on the dash does not need to appear a second time on that screen. In a sense, that makes sense.

There still is a way if you still insist: Create a symbolic link (or just copy) of the `.desktop` launcher of the program you want twice in your `~/.local/share/applications` folder, and give the link a different name, e.g. `~/.local/share/applications/firefox2.desktop`. Firefox now will appear twice in your Application overview.

Working with a symbolic link rather than a copy ensures that the duplicate remains the same as the original if that would be changed by a future update.